# C# serialization: xml comes out empty

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize an object into an xml file with SharpSerializer.

Unfortunately, the resulting xml files doesn't carry any of the information I'm feeding it.

My code is something like:

```
public class SaveGameInfo
{
    public string test;
}

public class main
{
    public void onClickedSave()
    {
        SaveGameInfo obj = new SaveGameInfo();
        obj.test = "TestInformation";
        SharpSerializer sharpSerializer = new SharpSerializer();
        sharpSerializer.Serialize(obj, "test.xml");
    }
}
```

The resulting XML carries only this information:

```
<Complex name="Root" type="SaveGameInfo, Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
```

Feels like I'm missing something obvious, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using properties instead of fields:

```
public class SaveGameInfo
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

public class main
{
    public void onClickedSave()
    {
        SaveGameInfo obj = new SaveGameInfo();
        obj.Test = "TestInformation";
        SharpSerializer sharpSerializer = new SharpSerializer();
        sharpSerializer.Serialize(obj, "test.xml");
    }
}
```

> [Note 2:](http://sharpserializer.codeplex.com/documentation) SharpSerializer serializes only object properties. Fields are
>   not serialized. If you like to serialize fields, they have to be
>   wrapped in properties.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this without using SharpSerializer.

```
public class main
{
    public void onClickedSave()
    {
        SaveGameInfo obj = new SaveGameInfo();
        obj.test = "TestInformation";
       obj.SerializeToXml("Test.xml");  
    }
}

public class SaveGameInfo
{
    public string test;

    public void SerializeToXml(string fullFileName)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveGameInfo));
        var textWriter = new StreamWriter(fullFileName);
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, this);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}
```